# Update an XML column value in sql

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I have got an XML column in sql table which needs to be updated. Say the structure is as follows:

```
<JPS>
 <P>
  <JP>
   <IsRequired>true</IsRequired>
   <Name>Folder</Name>
   <Value>C:\Test</Value>
  </JP>
  <JP>
   <IsRequired>false</IsRequired>
   <Name>Email Addresses</Name>
   <Value>a@a.com; b@b.com</Value>      
  </JP>
</P>
```

I want to update the email addresses in all the XML values in all the rows in the table to a specific value.
How can i achieve the same?

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 R2

Comment: This is really horribly bad design.... **do not** concatenate together multiple values into a single XML tag! Use multiple tags - XML is very flexible that way.... otherwise you have to resort to string matching and replacements with regexes and other ugly stuff....

Comment: Thanks Marc. I understand the design issue. But consider I have only one email address, but in that case how do we update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the contents of the `<Value>` element of the `<JP>` tag that has a `<Name>Email Addresses</Name>` value, then you can use something like this:

```
;WITH XmlEmail AS
(
SELECT 
    SomeUniqueID,  // some unique/primary key ID from your table - adapt as needed!
    JPReq = XJP.value('(IsRequired)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    JPName = XJP.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(20)'),
    JPValue = XJP.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
FROM 
    dbo.YourTable
CROSS APPLY
    YourXmlColumn.nodes('/JPS/P/JP[Name="Email Addresses"]') AS XTbl(XJP)
)
UPDATE dbo.YourTable
SET YourXmlColumn.modify('replace value of (/JPS/P/JP[Name="Email Addresses"]/Value/text())[1] with "newmail@test.tst"')
FROM XmlEmail xe 
WHERE dbo.YourTable.SomeUniqueID = xe.SomeUniqueID
```

This will update **all** rows, and **all** `<JP>/<Value>` nodes to the same value - is that what you're looking for?

**Update:** added support for checking and updating only those rows where the XML column actually does contain a `<JP>` tag with `Email Addresses` as its name - it requires that there is a **primary key** on your table (not sure what it is, since you didn't say anything about it) .... I've used `SomeUniqueID` as column name - **adapt to your table as needed!**

Comment: after running the update, it said all 60 rows are updated. But when opening each xml column value to verify I see that it is not updated actually. Also noticed that some rows are actually missing the Email Address tag name attribute in xml. How can we check in the update statement if the Email Address name tag exists in xml rows and then update.

Comment: I don't know your table structure, so it's kinda hard to suggest anything... I was trying to find out which rows contain that `Email Addresses` node, but in the end, I couldn't use that knowledge because I don't know how to **uniquely identify** a row in your table ...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in standard sql.

With standard sql you should read the relevant xml row one at a time, update the xml and insert it back.

Comment: You **can** of course do this is you're using a database system that supports XML datatypes and XML operations ...